# Pulling the file on Webdav to local in salesforce commerce cloud

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2c

I want to extract my file ,which is kept in a certain directory on webdav, to local with code.

I was able to create a sample link to download it, but I can't pull it to my local by sending an http get request from within the controller.

Simple Link:
https://zzz.salesforce.com/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Impex/src/catalog/Task14.xml

When I press this link, it downloads immediately from the browser, but I want to do these operations in the background in the code.

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you copy the code you already have into your question?

Answer (score 0):

In a script context, you should be able to access the file via the `dw.io` namespace classes. You can see the available classes in the documentation for the [dw.io namespace](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/scriptapi/html/api/package_dw_io.html?cp=0_20_2_18%5D).

Note that **you cannot access the filesystem from the storefront context**. Therefore whatever you want to do with that file must be done within the context of a Job or possibly an OCAPI hook. (I'm not sure on the hook) There is a group of quotas that prevent this from occurring. The list is found here: [dw.io quotas](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/quota/html/API_Quotas.html#category_I/O%20and%20Network). Note that all of the I/O APIs have a Storefront limit of `0`.

I'd recommend you check out the [FileHelper.js](https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/job-components/blob/master/cartridges/bc_job_components/cartridge/scripts/file/FileHelper.js) from the [job-components](https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/job-components/) library for examples and/or an abstraction layer for you to use. Then I also recommend examining how they built their [job steps](https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/job-components/tree/master/cartridges/bc_job_components/cartridge/scripts/jobsteps) so you can build a custom one for your needs as it's likely you'll need to build a job of some kind to do what you want to do. See the [job steps documentation](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/jobs/b2c_job_steps.html?cp=0_6_16_4) for more info on how to work with jobs and job steps.

You may also find that the [job-components](https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/job-components/) library already offers you what you need to do. I'm not sure because your question was pretty vague.